# Melhor forma de guardar dados do login

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde, qual seria a melhor forma de guardar dados do login de um usuário?
Tenho um sistema de login em PHP que valida usuário e senha via ajax e se estiver tudo ok, quero guardar os dados(email no caso) para ser utilizado em outros pontos do sistema. Pensei em utilizar sessão, porém acho que não dá pra criar/gravar uma sessão com javascript, então pensei em localStorage mas acho que isso não seria seguro.
Qual seria a melhor forma?
Utilizo PHP, jquery, ajax e javascript.
Grato.

Comment: Use `SESSION` do php.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, pensei nisso, porém como utilizo ajax para um login sem refresh da página, não sei como eu guardaria uma sessão considerando que javascript não manipula ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na validação do `ajax` você já pode setar as variaveis com os dados do banco.
vou fazer um exemplo bem pequeno só para exemplificar o uso do session, que salva a sessão em `php`

Após validar os dados no banco salve o nome, login, e qualquer outra váriavel que desejar nas `session`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["codigo_usuario"] = $query[1];
$_SESSION["nome_usuario"] = $query[2];
$_SESSION["permissao"] = $query[3];
$_SESSION["email"] = $query[4];
```

E para recuperar o dado desejado basta chama-lo, por exemplo se quiser saber a permissão basta chamar a `session` correspondente.

```
$_SESSION["permissao"];
```

E quando o usuário deslogar do sistema você destroi a `session` com o comando:

```
session_destroy();
```

Dessa forma você consegue armazenar os dados de uma sessão, não use senhas em sessão, elas podem ser capturadas caso o nível de criptografia seja fácil de quebrar.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de guardar login (e a mesma utilizada em diversos frameworks) certamente é a session. Eu meus projetos o laravel guarda na sessão sempre que um usuário loga ou desloga do site.

Um site que pode te esclarecer um forma melhor de se usar a superglobal $_SESSION[] estará nas referências.

[Uso adequado de sessions sem o uso de frameworks](https://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/sessoes-em-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo recomendo a utilização de um framework no back-end, estou usando em vários projetos o Codeigniter, o próprio framework cuida de todo o processo de login, registro e autenticação.

Ele já se encarrega de guardar os dados dos usuários bem como mantém uma tabela chamada ci_sessions para guardar as sessões.

Em cima desse framework é possível construir múltiplas aplicações, autenticando usuários em diversos aplicativos diferentes em cima da mesma base de dados.

https://codeigniter.com/